# smarty code definition {display

Tags: php, smarty

I can't understand this code

```
{display property=$theField.id}
```

This code snippet is from [**smartjobboard**](http://www.smartjobboard.com/) cms file is  **templates/_system/builder/bf_displaylisting_fieldsblocks.tpl** line **91** after parsing it produces this

```
echo $this->_plugins['function']['display'][0][0]->tpl_display(array('property' => $this->_tpl_vars['theField']['id']), $this);
```

smart job board uses [**smarty**](http://www.smarty.net/) as template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` is a smarty plugin function and `property` and argument to it. You need to search for something like:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("function","display", "... (local function name)");
```

in their code. Check the [manual about plugin functions](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl), and you know what's going on.

Comment: I searched but not found anything

Comment: It is not open source, I can't help. However it is surely a template function you can believe that.

Comment: thanks for the help I will find my way in but your direction helps me to find my way many many thanks